# Google test fixture as a member of class

Tags: c++, googletest

Suppose we have `TestFixture`

`class TestFixtureClass : public ::testing::Test {}`

Is it somehow possible to use this fixture in different one?
I mean normally create class object like with normal class.

```
template <typename Value>
class Different : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    Value value;
};

TYPED_TEST_CASE(Different, ::testing::Types<TestFixtureClass>);
```